# How to convert Map<String, Map<String, String>> to String?

Tags: java, collections

I have an entity

```
public class Report {
    private String departmentName;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private String currency;
}
```

and I want to calculate the amount for each department depending on the currency and write the result in the line.
Example:

```
    List<Report> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Report("Moscow", new BigDecimal(100), "USD"));
    list.add(new Report("Moscow", new BigDecimal(100), "USD"));
    list.add(new Report("Paris", new BigDecimal(100), "USD"));
    list.add(new Report("Moscow", new BigDecimal(200), "RUR"));
```

Result: `"Moscow 200 usd, Paris 100 USD, Moscow 200 RUR"`

For it:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> collect = list.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(doc -> doc.getDepartmentName(),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Report::getCurrency,
                            Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), doc -> {
                                BigDecimal sum = doc.stream()
                                        .map(A::getAmount)
                                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);

                                String cur = doc.stream().map(Report::getCurrency)
                                        .findFirst().get();
                                return sum.toString() + " " + cur;
                            }))));
```

And I receive a result:

```
{Paris={USD=100 USD}, Moscow={USD=200 USD, RUR= 200 RUR}} -- correct
```

but I don't know how to convert Map<String, Map<String, String>> to String

Comment: Please clarify what you mean to convert map to string. You have already converted it to string(using `.toString()`) to show the above result. Adding example of desired output format would greatly help.

Comment: @Chaosfire result of toString() = '{Paris={USD=100 USD}, Moscow={USD=200 USD, RUR= 200 RUR}}' but I need 'Paris - 100 USD, Moscow - 200 USD, Moscow- 200 RUR'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Desired result is `"Moscow 200 usd, Paris 100 USD, Moscow 200 RUR"`
> Try it like this using flatMap.

- stream the entrySet of the main map.
- flatMap the inner map's values via entrySet again.
- the using the key of the outer map and the value of the inner, map them to a string.
- Then join the strings with a collector.

```
String result = map.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                .map(e2 -> e.getKey() + " " + e2.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
Paris 100 USD, Moscow 200 RUR, Moscow 200 USD
```

Note:  Since maps are unordered, the order of the elements may not be consistent from run to run based on sums, additional Reports, etc.

I don't know if your Map is required as is or a way to get the result, but you could also do it like this.

- use groupingBy as before but use toMap as the collector.

```
Map<String, Map<String, BigDecimal>> map =
        list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Report::getDepartmentName,
                        Collectors.toMap(Report::getCurrency,
                                Report::getAmount, BigDecimal::add)));
```

- Then you would do it similar to before but convert the BigDecimal to a String here and append the currency type(`e2.getKey()`) to that.

```
String result = map1.entrySet().stream().flatMap(e -> e
                .getValue().entrySet().stream()
                .map(e2 -> e.getKey() + " " + e2.getValue().toString()
                        + " " + e2.getKey()))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```